# No such directory or file in C++ [Codeblocks/Visual Studio]

Tags: c++, curl, compiler-errors, codeblocks, include-path

I'm currently working on a project that will download a file from a website using the cURL library, but I'm currently getting an error when the compiler reaches the #include "curlpp/cURLpp.hpp" line. The IDE I'm using is Codeblocks with MinGW gcc compiler but I've also tried Visual Studio and I'm running into the same problem. The curl folder is located in the same folder as the source code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean curlpp folder not curl folder? Because the error is looking for curlpp not curl.

Comment: Hmm. If there is a curl folder. Does it have a curlpp subfolder. Perhaps the solution is to add ./curl to the additional includes of Visual Studio.

Comment: The curlpp is the main folder and all header files are in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar "path" issue. Try to change from:

```
#include "curlpp/cURLpp.hpp"
```

to:

```
#include "./curlpp/cURLpp.hpp"
```

In Visual Studio is also sometimes issue if your include directory is specified in VC++ Directories, put it rather into C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.